# Image registration with masks

Tags: python, image-processing, image-registration

How do I register images with masks on reference and target images? Which algorithms can I use for that? I do not simply want to crop ROIs. Masking needed across various regions of the images.

Comment: Such recommendations are unfortunately offtopic and questions about it get closed. The reason is that they get outdated soon. But instead of asking for a library how to achieve something you could directly ask for the real thing. I edited your question accordingly. However, you may need to provide more details, maybe examples to narrow the problem down a bit.

Comment: @Trilarion: algorithms do not age !?

Comment: @YvesDaoust True. I think it's implicitly included when asking how to do something but one can also explicitly ask for algorithms.